# Thruk installation "failed to open socket"

Tags: centos, nagios

I am extremely confused, and Google isn't really helping. Also, I'm kind of a Linux novice. I've taken a couple of classes, but that was all about how to configure things in a basic Linux setup. I'm now trying to learn how to set things up to actually use. At work we use Nagios/Thruk so I'm trying to set it up on my home network so I can learn it better.

I set up a CentOS 6.6 machine. I've installed Nagios on it, and that's working fine. Now I'm trying to set up Thruk. I've managed to get livestatus and Thruk installed, but I'm stuck at getting it to actually work. In the documentation it shows that I'm supposed to add these two lines to the `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg` file:

```
broker_module=/usr/local/lib/mk-livestatus/livestatus.o /var/lib/nagios/rw/live
event_broker_options=-1
```

the event_broker_options=-1 line already existed, so I added the other line above it. In some examples, it is shown as this instead:

```
broker_module=/usr/local/lib/mk-livestatus/livestatus.o /tmp/live.sock
event_broker_options=-1
```

I've tried both, and I cannot seem to get this to work. I've done all the basics I can think of. I've reinstalled and updated all of the components (nagios, livestatus, thruk), I've reloaded and restarted all service associated a billion times. When the line I added is in there, Nagios starts when I tell it to start, but it then stops immediately. When I go into the `/usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log` file, I see the following lines whenever I try to start Nagios and it fails:

```
Error: Could not load module '/usr/local/lib/mk-livestatus/livestatus.o' -> /usr/local/lib/mk-livestatus/livestatus.o: undefined symbol: last_command_check
Error: Failde to load module '/usr/local/lib/mk-livestatus/livestatus.o' .
Error: Module loading failed. Aborting.
```

If I comment out the line I added to the `nagios.cfg` file, Nagios will load and work properly, but Thruk still isn't working properly. If I load the Thruk page, I get this:

```
No Backend available
None of the configured Backends could be reached, please have a look at the logfile for detailed information and make sure the core is up and running.
Details:
home-net: ERROR: failed to open socket /tmp/live.sock: No such file or directory (/tmp/live.sock)
```

It appears to me to be something wrong with livestatus, but I don't understand it well enough to fix it on my own and I'm having a lot of difficulty finding (or maybe understanding) the answer anywhere. From what I understood, I thought the `nagios.cfg` file was supposed to configure the live.sock file. Is that not correct? I'm doing my best, but I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nagios 4.X make sure to install livestatus from the sources using the option to make it compatible with Nagios 4.X
-> https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html
Else Nagios can't create the socket during launching and crashes.
I am using exactly the same configuration you are, and still block on the next step : making thruk read the socket. If you manage it, please give details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! We recommend that users include relevant parts of articles they link to rather than post links only. This prevents the answers from becoming unusable if links become obsolete. Please edit your post and include most important points, if that's possible, to improve your answer.